# Start xubuntu 17.10 into RDP session

Tags: xubuntu, 17.10, xrdp, headless

I would like to have Xubuntu boot up, start some apps and then be able to connect to it via RDP.

Everything is working fine, other than the fact that my RDP session is not the same as the one that is originally logged into at boot.  I would like to be able to connect to the same session as is booted into if this is possible.

Comment: Have a look at `screen` and `tmux`. If I get you right they do what you want.

Comment: I can see how screen could do something similar to what I would like.  But it would only work for things running in the terminal.
Esentially right now if I have xubuntu boot up, it opens a local session.  But if I connect with RDP, it opens a new session.  I could access things with screen, but not everything.  I would like it if it would just have everything running right there on my display.

I can do this fine using vnc, but vnc is very slow, and poor quality compared to RDP.

Comment: I actually think screen might work for the most part... Not what I was thinking.  But how would I start a script at boot, in a detached screen?

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks! *Or* you could [edit] this question and reqord it to describe your current problem, as long as there's no answer yet.

Comment: Thanks!  I will do some searching on screen, but I am still curious about my original question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's not possible to access the console session through xRDP software (as far as I know).  xRDP open a different session than the console session.....

The only option available would be to use something like vnc software where you can access the console desktop. It's possible to have vnc service start at bootup. Because vnc service can be started at boot up, you would be able to connect through a vnc client to the correct desktop

Finally, you could also use the console option available in xRDP (so you can still use remote desktop client of your choice) and access the active desktop.  Obviously, the console option is basically telling xRDP software to make a vnc connection

Hope this help
till next time 
See ya